# Negate regular expression in Perl

Tags: regex, perl, negate

I am splitting a text file into blocks in order to extract those blocks which *do not* contain a certain line by using a regular expression.
The text file looks like this:

```
[Term]  
id: id1  
name: name1  
xref: type1:aab  
xref: type2:cdc  

[Term]  
id: id2  
name: name2  
xref: type1:aba  
xref: type3:fee
```

Someone helped me a few days ago by showing me how to extract those blocks which *do* contain a certain regular expression (for example "xref: type3"):

```
while (<MYFILE>) {
  BEGIN { $/ = q|| }
    my @lines = split /\n/;
    for my $line ( @lines ) {
        if ( $line =~ m/xref:\s*type3/ ) {
            printf NEWFILE qq|%s|, $_;
            last;
        }
    }
}
```

Now I want to write all blocks in a new file which do not contain "xref: type3". I tried to do this by simply negating the regex

```
if ( $line !~ m/xref:\s*type3/ )
```

or alternatively by negating the if statement by using

```
unless ( $line =~ m/xref:\s*type3/ )
```

Unfortunately it doesn't work - the output file is the same as the the original one. Any ideas what I'm doing wrong?

Comment: Don't use `!~` when you use `unless` -- it's a double negative, which is the same as the original.

Comment: Thanks, but that was just a typo.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You have:

*For every line, print this block if this line doesn't match the pattern.*

But you want:

*For every line, print this line if none of the other lines in the block match the pattern.*

As such, you can't start printing the block before you examined every line in the block (or at all lines until you find a matching line).

```
local $/ = q||;
while (<MYFILE>) {
    my @lines = split /\n/;

    my $skip = 0;
    for my $line ( @lines ) {
        if ( $line =~ m/^xref:\s*type3/ ) {
            $skip = 1; 
            last;
        }
    }

    if (!$skip) {
        for my $line ( @lines ) {
            print NEWFILE $line;
        }
    }
}
```

But there's no need to split into lines. We can check and print the whole block at once.

```
local $/ = q||;
while (<MYFILE>) {
    print NEWFILE $_ if !/^xref:\s*type3/m;
}
```

(Note the `/m` to make `^` match the start of any line.)

Answer (score 1):

Do not process the records line by line. Use a paragraph mode:

```
{   local $/ = q();
    while (<MYFILE>) {
        if (! /xref:\s*type3/ ) {
            printf NEWFILE qq|%s|, $_;
            last;
        }
}
```

Comment: Thanks for your help. I tried this solution but it only returned the very first block for me. Do I need to add a loop to process all the paragraphs?

Comment: @user2241303: If you want all the blocks, remove the `last` command.

Answer (score 1):

The problem is that you are using `unless` with `!~` which is interpreted as if `$line` does not *NOT* match do this. ( a double negative )

When using the `unless` block with the normal pattern matching operator `=~` you code worked perfectly, that is I see the first block as output because it does not contain type3.

```
LOOP:
while (<$MYFILE>) {
  BEGIN { $/ = q|| }
    my @lines = split /\n/;
    for my $line ( @lines ) {
        unless ( $line =~ m/xref:\s*type3/ ) {
            printf qq|%s|, $_;
            last LOOP;
        }
  }
}

# prints
# [Term]
# id: id1
# name: name1
# xref: type1:aab
# xref: type2:cdc
```

Comment: Thank you for you help, but all I get is an empty document although I copied the code and used exactly the same example.

Comment: I changed the printf statement to print to my console, add your `NEWFILE` handle back in to check or examine your terminal.

Comment: I added my NEWFILE handle but the output file is still empty. I'm truly at loss what to do. `#!/usr/bin/perl
open (MYFILE, 'inputfile');
open (NEWFILE, ">>", 'outputfile');

LOOP:
while (<$MYFILE>) {
  BEGIN { $/ = q|| }
    my @lines = split /\n/;
    for my $line ( @lines ) {
        unless ( $line =~ m/xref:\s*type3/ ) {
            printf NEWFILE qq|%s|, $_;
            last LOOP;
        }
  }
}`

Comment: take the `$` out before `MYFILE`, if you had `strict` and `warnings` on you would have seen the error.